# How do you show/hide content inside a form with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

How do you show/hide content in a form with jquery?  When I click this button it just wants to submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".hide1" ).toggle();
    $( ".show_next_div" ).click(function() {
        $( ".hide1" ).toggle();
    });        
});


<form method="post" action="form_submit_action.php">
    <button class="btn btn-primary show_next_div">Next Step</button>
    <div class="hide1">
       <p>something here hidden, now show with button press</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: replace button by input type="button"

Comment: That works!  Weird though... you would think they are the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586210/toggle-div-element-with-submitting-form-data gives more data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add type="button" to the button tag to stop the submit action

```
<form method="post" action="form_submit_action.php">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show_next_div">Next Step</button>
    <div class="hide1">
       <p>something here hidden, now show with button press</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note : there is another option like stop event or return false onsubmit at the form

Answer (score 0):

**A button usually triggers the form action unless you override it.**
So it is better to use **input type="button"**

Use the below in the form code - This should work !

```
<form method="post" action="form_submit_action.php">
    <input type = "button" class="btn btn-primary show_next_div" value="Next Step" ></input>
    <div class="hide1">
       <p>something here hidden, now show with button press</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the propagation and default action of the click event in the event listener closure.

```
$(".show_next_div").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".hide1").toggle();
});
```